# getServletContext()#getContext return null even after crossContext defined as true

Tags: servlets, context.xml, tomcat10

In the context `/inbox` deployed on tomcat10, I have added the file `META-INF/context.xml` with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Context crossContext="true" />
```

but when I try forward to another context, with:

```
getServletContext().getContext("/auth").getRequestDispatcher("/login").forward(request, response);
```

I got the error:

```
Cannot invoke "jakarta.servlet.ServletContext.getRequestDispatcher(String)" because the return value of "jakarta.servlet.ServletContext.getContext(String)" is null
```

What I am missing here?

the call above is used in this servlet from `/inbox`:

```
@WebServlet(name = "Home", urlPatterns = "/home")
public class Home extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    ...
    }
}
```

I also have tried the strings `/../auth` and `/../../auth` for the context, but the same error occurs.

Comment: The crossContext must be configured on the app you want to be available to other contexts. The symptoms indicate that you mistakenly configured it the other way round. Take a second look.

Comment: I made this change, and move the `META-INF/context.xml` file from the context `/inbox`  to the contexts `/auth` and `/admin` (that's the contexts I wanted to be available to other contexts; the context `/inbox` is calling in the servlet above). After that, I rebuild the projects, redeployed them, clear the cache in the browser and try access the endpoint again. same error occurred.

Comment: what should be the correct way to refer to the context in the argument for `getContext(...)`? just `/auth` or something else? (the endpoint for the servlet is '/inbox/home` -> url: `http://site1/inbox/home`. I am able to access the other context directly with something lime `http://site1/auth/login`)

Comment: Just the context path. So `/auth` and `/inbox` are completely fine. If it doesn't work for you then the context.xml being edited is most probably not the one being actually used by Tomcat. To figure out that we need to know the exact location of context.xml during runtime and how exactly you're starting Tomcat. Because more than often starters don't know that starting Tomcat from within an IDE such as Eclipse by default doesn't actually use the actual Tomcat installation but merely its engine. In such case you need to ensure that the build (Maven eg) places `META-INF/context.xml` in WAR file.

Comment: I verified the `/target` directory generated by maven, and located 2 places where the `META-INF` directory were present: 1) target/classes/META-INF and 2) target/<project-name)/META-INF. the seconf one is empty, and the file `context.xml` is placed on the location 1. I try start the tomcat from command line, either with command `bin/startup.sh` or with `service tomcat10 start`, and copy the war file to directories `~/apache-tomcat-10/webapps` and `/var/lib/tomcat10/webapp` respectively.

Comment: Extract/inspect the WAR file with a ZIP tool and check its META-INF folder. Does it contain the proper context.xml?

Comment: the WAR file has 2 META-INF folders: one in the root of the file, and another inside the directory WEB-INF/classes. the context.xml file is located inside of the second one.

Comment: Ha! There's your problem! It must be in the root META-INF. Perhaps build config wrong? Or perhaps even mistakenly placed in WEB-INF? In case of a default Maven project it's expected that the source file path is `src/main/webapp/META-INF/context.xml` and thus not e.g. `src/main/resources/META-INF/context.xml`. Let me know if this solves it all for you then I'll boil down an answer.

Comment: yes, that worked. I just change the location of the file context.xml from `/src/main/resources/META-INF` to `/src/main/webapp/META-INF`. In the directory `resources/META-INF` I had a `persistence.xml` file too, use by the EclipseLink. Is it possible place this file in the directory `/src/main/webapp/META-INF` too? Right now, it is not working in this directory, only in `resources/META-INF`.

Comment: `persistence.xml` is not a server-specific config file, it must be visible to the webapp's classloader in order for JPA to work. Hence, it has ultimately to end up somewhere in `WEB-INF/classes`.

Comment: yes, but can i customize the location of this file? defining as `/src/main/webapp/META-INF`  for instance?

Comment: Doesn't seem to. You can find all supported locations here: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.1-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context That's all up to Tomcat guys, it's not part of Servlet/WAR spec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `META-INF` folder containing the `context.xml` needs to be the one in the root of the WAR file, not the one in `WEB-INF/classes` folder. This is simply because it is as being a server-specific configuration file not supposed to be available in the classpath of the web application. In case of a default Maven project it's expected that the source file path is `src/main/webapp/META-INF/context.xml` and thus not e.g. `src/main/resources/META-INF/context.xml`.

Comment: just a correction: in the example, the `context.xml` should be placed in the `/inbox` context, not in the `/auth` context (`/inbox` forward to `/auth`, and `/auth` redirects back to `/inbox` after). the change that make the application work was the change in he location of the `context.xml` file (for `/src/main/webapp/META-ING`).

Comment: You're right. Answer has been updated.